# Preserving line segment ObjectIDs in point output from line Intersect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, intersection

I am using the Intersect tool in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 to identify all the intersections in a polyline shapefile.  The tool generates a point shapefile, but when I inspect the data it does not preserve the ObjectIDs from the original polyline file.

How can I preserve the two line segment ObjectIDs that create the intersection?

Comment: Take a look at [**Overlay Route Events (Linear Referencing)**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000009000000) which, after using [**Make Route Event Layer**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Route_Event_Layer/003m00000008000000/), should enable you to do a line-on-line overlay with a point output that keeps attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I have ArcGIS 10.2 installed. I just ran a test case using Intersect and it seems to preserve the line FID in the Point shapefile. The JoinAttributes parameter displays these options, NO_FID, ONLY_FID and ALL. Which option did you select?[image]

Comment: I just tried ONLY_FID but the program generated only one column of numbers, I was expecting 2 columns, 1st column FID of Road A, 2nd column FID of Road B